# how to solve too many arguments for public open fun get() Picasso! defined in com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, picasso, androidx

so I make use of Picasso Library and when I run my Apps I get the error I use Androidx API 30 to create my apps.

this is the error:  `too many arguments for public open fun get() Picasso! defined in com.squareup.picasso.Picasso`

this is my code :

```
class MainAdapter(val homeFeed: HomeFeed) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustumViewHolder>() {

    val videoTitles = listOf("First Title", "Second", "3rd")

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return homeFeed.videos.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustumViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_row, parent, false)
        return CustumViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustumViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val video = homeFeed.videos.get(position)
        holder?.view?.textView_video_title?.text = video.name

        holder?.view?.textview_channel_name?.text = video.channel.name

        val thumbnailImageView = holder?.view?.imageView_video_thumbnail

        Picasso.get(holder?.view?.context).load(video.imageUrl).into(thumbnailImageView)
    }
}

class CustumViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

}
```

this is the line of code leading to the error above :

```
    Picasso.get(holder?.view?.context).load(video.imageUrl).into(thumbnailImageView)
```

this is the screenshot of my error in my code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Uoj.png)

Comment: Just pass your activity context to the Picasso.get().

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I will add it as an answer for you. Please flag it as an answer then others will also find it helpful.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass your activity context to the `Picasso.get()`. Then it will be work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this version of  Picasso to your `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies 
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```